# How to read many sets of data from a file

Tags: c++

I have to read the four data elements viz student name, father's name, roll no and age from a file.
I am using inps as input file stream and outs as output data stream. I have 10 data sets in my input file. But this program writing only 1st data set in output file and ignoring rest 9 sets. Please give some suggestions to this problem.

```
string line;
int data;

while (inps) {

    getline(inps,line);    //read from file and put in line
    s1.setName(line);
    getline(inps,line);
    s1.setFatherName(line);
    inps>>data;
    s1.setRollNo(data);
    inps>>data;
    s1.setAge(data);

    outs.open("output",ios::app);
    outs<<"Student name: "<<s1.getName()<<endl<<"Father’s name: "
        <<s1.getFatherName()<<endl;
    outs<<"Roll number: "<<s1.getRollNo()<<endl<<"Age: "
        <<s1.getAge()<<endl<<endl;

    outs<<"============================================================="
        <<endl<<endl;
}

inps.close();
//write in output file
outs.close();
```

Comment: I even used for(i=0;i<10;i++) in place of while(inps). Even this is not working!
It is also reading only first set of data.

Comment: Why do you re-open `outs` every time? Just open it once before the loop.

Comment: Its working fine now. Thanks:) 
But I was opening the file in append mode. Why was that a problem?

Comment: You didn't close it before re-opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't continually re-open the same ofstream:

1. at all, it's just silly
2. certainly not without closing it properly first

Answer (score 1):

Another problem in this program is that while entering in the loop, it checks inps==0 or not and still its uninitialized!
So, instead of while(inps), we have to write for(getline(inps,line);line!="";getline(inps,line))

and then remove very first line of code and it all works nicely.